# Simple way to encode data on flash drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, ubuntu-12.04, base64

I have a USB flash drive and would like to base-64 (or similar) encode all the files/folders (recursively) under a certain parent directory on it; let's call it "toEncode".

It would be preferable to be able to encode and decode these files whenever I want: decode the toEncode directory, modify any part of its child folders/files, and then re-encode it. I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 desktop. Ideas?

Comment: **Encoding** is not the same as **encrypting**. The former translates data from one representation to a smaller code set (for example Unicode to ASCII) and the latter translates (generally) into a binary form unreadable without some secret code.

Comment: Thanks but I know the difference and do mean encode!

Comment: If so, what is the **use case**? I can't think of any reason why you'd want to do this, but maybe you have one?

Comment: The use case is irrelevant backstory that shouldn't be used to clutter up the SU databases. I'm simply wondering if this is possible and if so how

Comment: You'll have it much easier if you break your problem into its constituents:  You want to do one operation recursively on several files; the operation happens to be base64 encoding/decoding.  Both parts taken by themselves are trivial, without knowing what you are trying to accomplish it's difficult to give any meaningful advice.

Comment: Why not just write a simple program to do it?  It's maybe 200 lines of Java, if you have the Base64 routine already.  Probably a bit more complicated in C.  Anyone with basic programming skills should be able to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To encode:

```
base64 file.xyz > encoded.b64
```

To decode:

```
base64 -d encoded.b64 > file.xyz
```

For more information:

```
man base64
```

To find such commands, it's useful to search using commands like these:

```
apropos -r 'base.*64'
apt-cache search 'base.*64'
```

Comment: Awesome thanks @I0b0 (+1) do you know if base64 is recursive and works on directories?

Comment: Nope, it's definitely one file at a time. I don't think your use case is really all that common, so it might help avoiding an [X-Y problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) if you post more details.

Comment: Of course not: As a filter, by design it works on single files only.  You'll have to build the recursion yourself, maybe by a combination of `find` and a little scripting.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to encrypt data on a flash drive, there are far better tools than trying to do it manually.

http://www.truecrypt.org/

Comment: Thanks @codenoire (+1) but I do want base 64 **encoding** here... Ideas?

Comment: You might be thinking of what happens if you need to stop this sort of operation during the middle of processing a whole bunch of files.  Some will be encoded, and some will not.  If any of the original set of files were actually already base64-encoded data, you're going to have a heck of a time trying to recover.